# What is the word with the definition: "One that is modulated"?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, grammar, word-usage

If I employ someone, then they are my "employee".

If my computer program modulates other computer programs, then they are my computer program's _____.?

I can't find any reference to "modulatee" anywhere. What is the word that I should use?

Is there an alternative word that captures that definition of "modulate" (monitor and alter when needed)  and can be used in this way?

Comment: Hello, Josh. There are lexical gaps in English; there may not be a suitable word here, and you may have to use a clause. Additionally, 'modulate' doesn't usually take a sentient object. 'Moderate' more commonly does.

Comment: What do you mean by *modulate someone*?

Comment: @V0ight The context that I actually have is "My computer program modulates other computer programs, therefore they are my computer program's _____."

Comment: The appropriate alternative depends on the specific sense of your example, that is, how does your program modulate others? Does it separate the others' code into modules? Does it temper the others' effects in some way? Does it intervene between others and some third program or programs?

Comment: "supervisee" normally apply to a person, but may fit with a computer.

Comment: @JEL The definition that I need is more along that lines of "monitor and alter when needed". Program A updates Program B's variables when it sees fit.

Comment: Without making heavy weather of it, you can use *-ee*: "...subsequently the terminations *-or* and *-ee* were **freely added** to English vb.-stems to form ns., those in *-or* denoting the agent, and those in *-ee* the passive party" (*OED Online*, bold emphasis mine).

Comment: @JEL ~ what do you say to the variant "modulate-ee", in light of the fact that "modulate" already ends in 'e' and an additional one could look as if it were a typo

Comment: @V0ight, I'd say that adding the suffix to the stem (*modulat-*) is entirely warranted, but not adding it to the inflected form. I'm rarely inclined to cater to the whims and misapprehensions of a small subset of readers, especially at the price of formal coherence or accuracy.

Comment: I see the dictionary does suggest this sort of usage for *modulate*, but I have never heard it in my entire life. I'd suggest you use *regulate*, if that is what you mean. *Control* or *administer* seem like other options. *Modulate*, in my experience, is used to refer to waveforms, sounds, flows, and other continuous analog functions. It just seems entirely out of place in a digital setting.

Comment: Just ask a ham -- the *carrier* is *modulated*.

Comment: Do you mean that your program changes the values passed to the other programs' parameter variables, changes the values of the other programs' internal variables, or changes the definitions of the other programs' internal and parameter variables (say from integer to currency or text to date)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked:

> If my computer program modulates other computer programs, then they
>   are my computer program's _____.?

The best fit I could think of  is "***[slaves](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slave)***" based on widespread usage in technology-related literature.

> **slave**: a device (as the printer of a computer) that is directly
>   responsive to another

*Your computer program* would then be their *master*.

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master/slave_(technology):

> Master/slave is a model of communication where one device or process
>   has unidirectional control over one or more other devices.

**Disclaimer**: You are alerted to potential political correctness implications. A couple of alternatives to **master/slave** that I found are **primary/replica** and **leader/follower**.